# How to create grafana alerts for metrics with labels?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I have a metric with two labels. Let's say `source` (`srcA` and `srcB`) and `event_type` (`typeA` and `typeB`). I need to create an alert when `typeA - typeB <= 0` for every `source`. The number of sources may vary.

How can I configure such condition? To use labels in conditions definition.

Comment: Whenever you trying to apply arithmetic operations to labels, you should stop and reevaluate what you are doing. Grafana doesn't support that. But if your data source supports this, you probably can do something.